# WPF Combobox binding and SelectedValue with SelectedValuePath

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, selectedvalue

I am really struggling with data binding and the MVVM Methodology, though I like the concept I am just struggling.  I have created a WPF for that has multiple comboboxes and a button.  The first combobox will list database instance names.  the remaining comboboxes will be populated after the button is clicked.  Since I am having issues with the first, database instances, combobox I will only show my code for that.  When the application starts up the combobox is loaded and the first item is selected, as expected. The issue is when I select a new name my method that I expect to get called does not.  Can someone help me to understand why my method `public DBInstance SelectedDBInstance` is not getting executed when I have this in my XAML, `SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDBInstance, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`?

Here is my XAML for the database instances combobox.  One question I have here is the "value" fpr SelectedValuePath, if I change it to say "DBInstanceName" it does not work.

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cbxRLFDBInstances" ItemsSource="{Binding DBInstances}" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDBInstance, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  SelectedValuePath="value" DisplayMemberPath="DBInstanceName"/>
```

Here is my ViewModel Code:

```
namespace DatabaseTest.ViewModel
{

class RLFDatabaseTableViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Utilities dbtUtilities = new Utilities();


    public RelayCommand LoadDBInfoCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public RLFDatabaseTableViewModel()
    {
        LoadDBInstances();

        LoadDBInfoCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadDBInfo);
    }


    public ObservableCollection<DBInstance> DBInstances
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public void LoadDBInstances()
    {
        ObservableCollection<DBInstance> dbInstances = new ObservableCollection<DBInstance>();
        DataTable dt = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(false);

        dbInstances.Add(new DBInstance { DBInstanceName = "fal-conversion\\mun2012ci" });
        dbInstances.Add(new DBInstance { DBInstanceName = "fal-conversion\\mun2014ci" });

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                dbInstances.Add(new DBInstance { DBInstanceName = dr["Name"].ToString() });
            }
        }

        DBInstances = dbInstances;

    }


    private DBInstance _selectedDBInstance;


    public DBInstance SelectedDBInstance
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedDBInstance;
        }

        set
        {
            _selectedDBInstance = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDBInstance");
            //ClearComboBoxes();

        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my Model code.  When I step through the code this method, `public string DBInstanceName`, gets executed multiple time.  I do not know why and it is seems wasteful to me.

```
namespace DatabaseTest.Model
{
public class RLFDatabaseTableModel { }


public class DBInstance : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string strDBInstance;


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return strDBInstance;
    }


    public string DBInstanceName
    {
        get
        {
            return strDBInstance;
        }

        set
        {
            if (strDBInstance != value)
            {
                strDBInstance = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DBInstanceName");
            }
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of setting the SelectedValuePath?

Comment: I was just trying everything I saw. Nothing seems to work

Comment: Try removing the SelectedValuePath and see what happens.

Comment: I have been running it without it, my SelectedDBInstance code is never executed

Comment: What about changing SelectedValue to SelectedItem?

Comment: I did not try that. I'll give that a try

Comment: I changed it to SelectedValue to SelectedItem and That now causes the SelectedDBInstance to now be called, but now I do not have an item selected when the application starts up.  I tried SelectIndex and that didn't work.

Comment: I figured out how to set the first item in the combobox

Comment: I have another question in conjunction with this.  Now that I have the Database Instances combobox working I need to be able to get the selected contents of the combox in order to load the next combobox.  After the Database Instance class has been loaded, I am now working with a database names class.  I need the database instance name contained in the Database Instance combobox.  I have tried DBInstance dbInstanceName = new DBInstance();  and then I do dbInstanceName = SelectedDBInstance, but SelectedDBInstance is null.  How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to the `SelectedDBInstance` property and get rid of the `SelectedValuePath`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxRLFDBInstances" ItemsSource="{Binding DBInstances}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDBInstance, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="DBInstanceName"/>
```

The `SelectedValuePath` property is only used when you want to bind to a source property that is not of the same type as the item in the `ItemsSource` collection.

To select an item initially you should set the `SelectedDBInstance` property to an item that is present in the `DBInstances` collection:

```
public RLFDatabaseTableViewModel()
{
    LoadDBInstances();
    LoadDBInfoCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadDBInfo);
    SelectedDBInstance = DBInstances[0]; //selected the first item
}
```